# SQL using Case to produce a Yes/No result from a SUM operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to query 3 tables to produce a dataset that produces a Yes/No result based on whether there are any fields in one of the tables that meet the criteria and grouping this by the customer. It's probably easiest to explain by giving an example of the code and results I'm trying to achieve.

There are 3 tables, customers, orders, and products and I want a list of customers that have ordered specific products and then a simple yes no rating on whether any of those products are fragile. I can get the results I want if I count the number of fragile products likeso:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name,
sum(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Products Ordered",
sum(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) AND p.fragility IN(4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Fragile product?"
FROM customers_details c OUTER JOIN orders o ON (c.cust_id = o.cust_id)
OUTER JOIN products p l ON (o.product_id = p.product_id)
GROUP BY c.cust_id, c.cust_name
```

This will produce the following:

```
cust_id | cust_name | Products Ordered | Fragile product? 
100 | Joe Bloggs    | 2                | 1
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 3                | 2
```

But what I want is for the last column to give a simple yes/no, so I've tried this:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name,
sum(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Products Ordered",
CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) AND p.fragility IN(4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END "Fragile product?"
FROM customers_details c OUTER JOIN orders o ON (c.cust_id = o.cust_id)
OUTER JOIN products p l ON (o.product_id = p.product_id)
GROUP BY c.cust_id, c.cust_name, o.purchases
```

However that produces a dataset likeso:

```
cust_id | cust_name | Products Ordered | Fragile product?
100 | Joe Bloggs    | 1                | YES
100 | Joe Bloggs    | 1                | NO
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 1                | YES
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 1                | YES
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 1                | NO
```

I've tried using SELECT DISTINCT but that just removes one of the Jane Bloggs entries like so:

```
cust_id | cust_name | Products Ordered | Fragile product? 
100 | Joe Bloggs    | 1                | YES
100 | Joe Bloggs    | 1                | NO
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 2                | YES
200 | Jane Bloggs   | 1                | NO
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I'm querying a PostgreSQL DB.

Edit: Using outer join because we want a full list of customers, and all orders that met the criteria rather than just the ones that are fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put the case when outside the sum:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name,
sum(CASE WHEN p.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Products Ordered",
CASE
  WHEN
    sum(CASE WHEN p.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) AND p.fragility IN(4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  THEN
    'Yes'
  ELSE
    'No'
END "Fragile product?"
FROM customers_details c OUTER JOIN orders o ON (c.cust_id = o.cust_id)
OUTER JOIN products p l ON (o.product_id = p.product_id)
GROUP BY c.cust_id, c.cust_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly, but you could try:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) AND p.fragility IN(4,5) THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END) "Fragile product?"
```

If you have to see a literal 'no' then you could wrap it in a COALESCE statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `case` *outside* the `sum()`:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name,
       sum(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000,2000,3000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Products Ordered",
       (CASE WHEN sum(CASE WHEN o.purchases IN(1000, 2000, 3000) AND p.fragility IN(4,5)
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0
                      END) > 0
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) "Fragile product?"
FROM customers_details c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.cust_id = o.cust_id LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON o.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id, c.cust_name;
```

I am not familiar with such a thing as `OUTER JOIN`, so I replaced it with `LEFT JOIN`.